Is there a well-known digital logic circuit that outputs the last valid input on a high impedence input?
I'm wondering if there is a well-known digital logic circuit with this kind of logic:



Input
Output




0
0


1
1


z
last valid input



The context is that I have a device that is enabled/disabled depending if the input is on or off. However, there is a possibility the input may be accidentally disconnected, and I would like the device to remember its previous state, as turning the device on/off is very costly.

If the input is truly disconnected, and it is an high z input, it is allowed by definition to wander up and down depending on a number of factors. If this wandering brings the input into a valid state, how can you distinguish this situation from a legit driving of the pin? While you got good answers already, it seems to me that this question lacks a bit of information to be fully answered - ultimately you are the designer of the system and know for sure though.

Yes - this is known as a "bus hold" or "bus keeper" circuit, often built into buffers/transceivers, but which could also be realized with your own weak driver (e.g. a buffer + a series resistor as described in the diagram here).
However, taking the context

"However, there is a possibility the input may be accidentally disconnected, and I would like the device to remember its previous state, as turning the device on/off is very costly."

into account, it might be worth seeing if you can store this state in some higher-level system (e.g. another microcontroller in your design); I usually see bus keepers used to latch a bus when it's not driven, rather than store major system state, although there's not necessarily any electrical reason against it.

Selecting this answer because you gave me a name I can find on Wikipedia, while being more informative than a previous answer

A non-inverting hold circuit will do what you want

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you don't have a non-inverting buffer to hand, cascading two inverting buffers will also work

A common way to implement this is with two Schmitt trigger inverters in series, such as as a CD40106, 74HC14, CD4093, 74AC132, or any other logic family that is appropriate for the input signal.

@AnalogKid: I wonder why, so far as I know, there has never been a standard "bus keeper" chip which would include e.g. twelve Schmidtt-trigger inverters and twelve inverters with very weak outputs in a 14-pin package, or perhaps a 16-pin variant with a couple of control pins that could select between bus hold, weak pull-up, weak pull-down, or "off" functions (e.g. 00=off; 01=pullup; 10=pulldown; 11=bus-hold).

Well, I wouldn't call it a digital logic circuit because what you are asking for is the detection of an open circuit and, that will be a circuit that contains an analogue input.
The easiest example I can think of is using a non-inverting comparator with enough hysteresis to remain "latched" at the previous output state when the input becomes high-impedance: -

Image from Curing Comparator Instability with Hysteresis from ADI. Set the reference voltage to mid-rail and use enough hysteresis (R1/R2) so that it latches when the input is open circuit but, not too much hysteresis causing it to not properly respond to a proper logic level.

Yes there is. Many buffers have a feature called "bus hold".
